# Android HTTP Post to a URL without parameters

Tags: android, performance, http

um quite new to android and tried  to do a post to a URL by android . My URL looks like this.

```
                 http://192.168.101.111:7000/MyService.svc/home/updatejob/4600/XCV13030001/TTTT0000/CCCC0000/SSSS0000
```

I can do a post to this url via Advance rest client and this works fine. This is my android code implementation

```
public boolean updateInfo() {
    boolean result = false;
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sbDriverID", sbDriverID.toString()));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sbJobNumber", sbJobNumber.toString()));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sbTrailerNumber", sbTrailerNumber.toString()));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sbContainerNumber", sbContainerNumber.toString()));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("sbSealNumber", sbSealNumber.toString()));
    try {
        UrlEncodedFormEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8");
        httpPost.setEntity(entity);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        if (httpResponse != null) {
            if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 204)
                result = true;
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

This returns me a 404. I tried so hard and could not find a reason.

Comment: The URL above says "couldn't connect".

Comment: Thats a location server

Comment: @Kalanamith what does your browser show, when you try to access the URL?

Comment: URL Can be accessed its in my local host. Used Advance Rest client and works well , but when I tried to post the data via Android it returns me  a 404

Comment: Is your android device in the same 192.168.x.x sub domain?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to open the URL (using the browser) from the same Android device that can't connect? Maybe Android device is in a different domain.